# Add Interceptors to Camel Route

Tags: caching, routes, apache-camel, servlet-filters, interceptor

I am working on a application using Apache Camel Routes to process the requests. I want to add caching to each of the routes. So, that if the requested data is already in cache, we do not need to execute the processing in the route, otherwise the route logic would be executed.

I want to know how we can transparently add caching to each of the routes. I initially thought of adding a check for cached content at start of route and proceeding based on the results. Also, a step to add the route response to cache at end of the route. But, I think this approach makes caching logic coupled with route logic.Bu,stil we know what to cache and if we have to cache if it is within the routes.

I am looking for a way which I can use to add this as Aspect as in AOP.

Is this possible in Camel. I have seen there is a interceptor in camel. But, still its part of the  route, so no separation from route logic.

Is there way we can transparently add caching to each of the routes.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, but maybe the cache component can help you, see http://camel.apache.org/cache.html.

So in your case, call the CHECK operation, if the data exists end the route, if not call the ADD operation and do the further processing of the route.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, it still is mixed with routing logic. I do not see cache component providing a way to be decoupled from routes. I am looking for decoupling them.

Comment: Ok, but camel interceptor, see http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html, should fit your needs then.

Comment: I think I already said that in my question, that Interceptor is still coupled with routing logic.

Comment: Yes, but according to the documentation you can set/configure the interceptor globally for all routes in the camel context.